# Remote camera security

Tags: 11.04, software-recommendation, security

For Ubuntu 11.04

I need an application that will monitor and record 4 CCTV cameras w/sound. Need playback of the recorded activity with timestamp. It should be able to control zoom and camera angle via joystick or mouse. It would be nice to have it stream live feed over ssh too.
Minimal resources available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try ZoneMinder

[http://www.zoneminder.com](http://www.zoneminder.com/)

Info about ZoneMinder from ZoneMinder.com

> ZoneMinder is an integrated set of applications which provide a
>   complete surveillance solution allowing capture, analysis, recording
>   and monitoring of any CCTV or security cameras attached to a Linux
>   based machine.